# Securing the primary Ansible user

Tags: ssh, configuration, configuration-management, ansible

It seems that there are only two reasonable approaches for the primary Ansible user:

- Using `root`
- Using another user (e.g., `ansible`) with `NOPASSWD` `sudo` access

The first option is a no-go since I cringe at the thought of keeping `PermitRootLogin` on. So, by default, the 2nd option seems to be the way to go.

I was thinking, at the very least, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User ansible
    PasswordAuthentication No
```

And limiting key usage to the Ansible host by using the `from` option in `authorized_keys`:

```
from="192.168.100/24"
```

Any other ideas or issues/concerns with my thoughts so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the measures that I use for clients that have to be managed remotely by ssh (in my case using BackupPC instead of Ansible, but it works the same way).

If you're only using ssh to manage the clients, not for shell access, then it will improve security to add

```
AllowUsers ansible
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a user account that requires a password for SUDO access and provide that value at run-time via the `--ask-sudo-pass` flag (`-K`) for ansible-playbook

```
ansible-playbook -i inv/production -K playbook.yml
```

see http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html for more details